# Android Studio custom Keyword appearance coloring

Tags: android, android-studio, keyword, custom-keyword

I use the Log.i(String, String) method a lot. I would like to have that method, and only that method, have a specific color font so I can quickly identify it.

I looked in Preferences > Editor > Colors and Fonts > Custom and found a screen listing options for keyword1, keyword2...

Problem: I can't figure out this Keyword1 item.
Is there a place where I can define my own keyword? If so, where? Can I use it to act like my Log.i method?